# How do I create a specimen builder in AutoFixture to always return a string that matches a Regex?

Tags: unit-testing, autofixture

I am trying to use conventions in my unit tests which make use of AutoFixture.  I have a Password value object as shown:

```
public class Password : SemanticType<string>
{
    private int _daysPasswordValid;

    public Password(string password) : base(IsValid, password)
    {
        Guard.NotNullOrEmpty(() => password, password);
        Guard.IsValid(() => password, password, IsValid, "Invalid Password");

        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    static bool IsValid(string candidate)
    {
        //password cannot contain be whitespace
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(candidate))
            return false;

        const string passwordPattern = @"^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&=()-*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{20}$";

        var match = Regex.Match(candidate, passwordPattern);

        return match.Success;
    }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }

    public int DaysPasswordValid
    {
        get { return _daysPasswordValid; }
        set
        {
            const int minimunDays = 0;
            const int maximumDays = 90;

            if (value <= maximumDays && value > minimunDays)
                _daysPasswordValid = value;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    "Password must be valid more than {0} and no more than {1} days.".Fmt(minimunDays, maximumDays));
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Password password)
    {
        return password.Value;
    }

    public static explicit operator Password(string value)
    {
        return new Password(value);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to create a fixture based on the Password class and have the fixture created with a valid password, in other words, a password that matches the RegEx pattern in the Password class.  I have been looking at the RegularExpressionGenerator available in AutoFixture but haven't quite gotten things to work.  Here is the builder have so far:

```
public class ValidPasswordBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public ValidPasswordBuilder(string regularExpressionRequest)
    {
        PasswordRegularExpression = regularExpressionRequest;
    }

    public string PasswordRegularExpression { get; private set; }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as ParameterInfo;
        if (pi != null && pi.Name == "password" && pi.ParameterType == typeof(string))
        {
            var generator = new RegularExpressionGenerator();
            var regExRequest = new RegularExpressionRequest(PasswordRegularExpression);
            var result = generator.Create(regExRequest, context);
            return result.ToString();
        }

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
[Fact]
    public void ValidPasswordMatches()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new ValidPasswordBuilder(PasswordPattern));
        Action a = () => fixture.Create<Password>();
        a.ShouldNotThrow<ArgumentException>();
    }
```

I can run the test as setup above, and it passes, but if I debug it, I get an error in the IsValid function in the Password class (through the Guard clause) that says that the password returned from the builder is:

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.NoSpecimen

I never seem to get a result that matches the RegEx pattern.  I feel like I'm close, but need some help getting over the hump.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As it looks like, the pattern you use is not supported:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&=()-*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{20}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Try with a different Regular Expression.

**Edit**: Or try doing [this](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/267#issuecomment-39553812) or [this](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/267#issuecomment-38951754), in order to configure AutoFixture to use a different Regular Expression, without changing the `Password` class.

---

AutoFixture turns Regular Expressions into [Automatons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) by applying the algorithms of [dk.brics.automaton](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/).

You may use a different pattern or use a different *engine* to reverse the Regular Expression into an Automaton. As an example, you can use the [Rex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/rex/) engine.

Though, even with Rex your Regular Expression is not supported, as the following constructs are currently not supported by Rex:

anchors \G, \b, \B, named groups, lookahead, lookbehind, as-few-times-as-possible quantifiers, backreferences, conditional alternation, substitution.

---

If you want to try Rex with AutoFixture you can use the following generator:

```
internal class RexRegularExpressionGenerator : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (request == null)
            return new NoSpecimen();

        var regularExpressionRequest = request as RegularExpressionRequest;
        if (regularExpressionRequest == null)
            return new NoSpecimen();

        var pattern = regularExpressionRequest.Pattern;

        try
        {
            var regex = RexEngine
                .GenerateMembers(
                    new RexSettings(pattern) { k = 1 })
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (Regex.IsMatch(regex, pattern))
                return regex;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, you can download Rex only as a .NET application (.exe) file which you can then reference like any other managed assembly in your project.

Comment: This worked a treat for me because I wasn't happy with the strings that the OoTB RegularExpressionGenerator was creating ("\d" seemed to always create a "0").  Rex.exe is compiled as x86 so I used dotpeek 10 to decompile and rebuilt as a DLL and used the above Generator and it is amazing: \d will generate more than just 0-9, including tamil and all manner of funky unicode digits.  (made us change our regexes from \d to [0-9] explicitly